# Add values from dictionary

Tags: dictionary, sum

I have created a dictionary, and I want to add the values from each item in the dictionary. Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys
import re
import collections
import numpy as np

dict = {'x':['x',0], 'y':['y',0], 'z':['z',0]}
```

I am then using an input file to count the instances of x, y, and z and add them to the dictionary:

```
with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        count_lines += 1
        num_lines += 1
        num_words += len(words)
        title = line
        for key in dict:
            title = line
            if re.search(key, title):
                trusted[key][1]+=1
                title = re.sub(key,dict[key][0],title)
                while re.search(key, title):
                    dict[key][1]+=1
                    title = re.sub(key,dict[key][0],title)
        dict_values = dict.values()
        output_file.write('Dict:', sum(dict_values[1:-1]))
```

Then my dictionary would be, for example: `dict = {'x':['x',6], 'y':['y',10], 'z':['z',8]}`, and I want to add 6, 10, and 8 together.

I have tried this with and without the string split, I have tried assigning the sum equation to a variable and writing the variable, etc. I am continuously getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'" and "TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable" error messages.

Comment: This is what you need `sum([dict[x][1] for x in dict])`. If you want to use `dict_values` instead, you can use `sum([x[1] for x in dict_values])`.

Comment: You can also use `sum([y[1] for x, y in dict.items()])`.